# WIQL query to return all test cases that have attachments?

Tags: c#, tfs, wiql

Here's my current code to return all the TFS Test Case work items that have attachments, from a specific project:

```
public IEnumerable<ITestCase> TestCasesWithAttachments(ITestManagementTeamProject project)
{
    return
        project.TestCases.Query("SELECT [Id], [Title] FROM WorkItems WHERE State<>'Closed'")
        .Where(tc => tc.Attachments.Count > 0);
}
```

This not efficient because it is checking the attachment count using Linq on the result of the query.

Is there any way to check for test cases with a nonzero attachment count in the WIQL string itself?

I've tried things like `SELECT [Id], [Title] FROM WorkItems WHERE State<>'Closed' AND AttachmentCount<>0` to no avail...

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the following code:

```
project.TestCases.Query("SELECT [id], [title] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.AttachedFileCount]>0 ");
```